# How to make a table with a jump in range?

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation

I'd like to use Table to generate a list of numbers that includes a gap. For instance, this accomplishes what I want:

```
α = π/2;
X1 = Table[-Q1 + α, {Q1, α, α/√3, -0.01}];
X2 = Table[-Q1 + α, {Q1, -2 α/√3, -2 α/√3 - 1/3, -0.01}];
X = Join[X1, X2];
```

However, I'd like to do this within one Table line, because I'd like to use Manipulate to run through the list `X`. Alternatively, is there a straightforward way to use Manipulate with the list `X` that I currently have. Either would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: As an alternative to the answer by @Johu, you can let a single `Table` variable go from start to finish with a constant step, but let the expression evaluates to `Nothing` when the variable is out of an interval. `Nothing` gets discarded.

Comment: This might be useful. I'm trying to use the list within a `DynamicModule`, and I basically need a slider to run over the elements in the list `X`. I still haven't figured that out...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would generate the list of parameters beforehand and use `Table[expr,{i,{i1,i2,...}}]`

```
α = π/2;
qList = Range[α, α/√3, -0.01] ~Join~ Range[-2 α/√3, -2 α/√3 - 1/3, -0.01];
X = Table[-Q1 + α, {Q1, qList}];
```